# I feel that my manager slows my work, how to deal with it?

Tags: productivity, management

It seems strange, but my manager sits right next to me and, well, when he isn't near, I feel free, and I'm planning, doing, etc, doing my work with flashes in the eyes, feel accomplishments.

But everything is opposite when he's on his workplace, I simply have to force myself to do anything, I'm feeling very much worried and nervous and my brain doesn't work normally. How to deal with it?

Comment: You definitely are doing something which you think you should not be doing.

Comment: Why do you feel uncomfortable when your superior is near?

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer Not necessarily. I can barely function when I'm working on a project and my boss (or client) is standing there, watching me work. It's nerve-wracking because I feel like I'm under constant scrutiny from someone who knows less about what I'm doing than I do. (OP, do you work for a software company? Is your manager a programmer, too?)

Comment: With a blunt or sharp object, and a nearby river?

Comment: @haylem http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=4865182#4865182

Comment: @YannisRizos: There should be a standard about how to deal with these. Maybe the FBI has a pocket guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried talking to your manager about it? You (by which I really mean "you two", a word Germanic languages lost a while back) need to work out what's wrong when the two of you are together.

- Is he doing something that puts you off? If so, is it something that he can stop doing or you can stop worrying about?
- Are you afraid of doing something wrong that he'll notice? If so, is it something he actually cares about, or are you worried over nothing? Have you ever talked about what he thinks of your work?
- Do you just not like the guy? If so, can you arrange to work somewhere you don't have to deal with him?

Comment: Off-topic nitpick: The plural "you" is still very much present in German in form of "ihr". So, it might be that just English lost it a while back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to socialize more with your manager. Go together to lunch more often. Start a conversation with him more often, maybe something not work related - that's easy. Start with short conversations, maybe comment on the weather, why not? You might be feeling intimidated by him and you have to work through that. Avoidance is not a good strategy to deal with such problems.